# SWIG C++ to Python: Initialize class by struct reference not working

Tags: python, c++, reference, swig

I have a C++ library that contains a class that is constructed using a reference to a struct:

myclass.hpp:

```
className::className (params& pars): memberInitList 
{
//some code that modifies state of params
}
```

My swig interface file looks like

myInterface.i:

```
%module MyLibrary
%{
     #include "myclass.hpp"
%}

%include "include/myclass.hpp"
```

according to section 33.3.9 of the [SWIG documentation](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/SWIGDocumentation.html), SWIG should be able to handle this case just fine, but when executing the resulting python package, I get the error:

```
TypeError: in method 'new_className', argument 1 of type 'params &'
```

SWIG should be able to handle the pass-by-reference just fine, so I'm not sure what is the issue here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit:
I have already looked around the internet for possible solutions, including the SWIG documentation, but no solution has worked.
I have tried

```
%include <typemaps.i>
%apply params &INPUT { params& params}
Binary::Binary(params& params)
```

but this doesnt work.

edit: MWE
Heres a very minimal working example that is the basic working of my code and reproduces exactly my error:

example.hpp

```
#ifndef included
#define included
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using high_prec_t=double; //boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<25>;
struct tmpStruct {
    high_prec_t x { 0. };
    std::string y { "hello" };
    int z { 0 };
    std::vector<high_prec_t> w{};
    double f{0.};
};
class tmpClass
{
    protected:
        high_prec_t m_x;
        std::string m_y;
        int m_z;
        std::vector<high_prec_t> m_w;
        double m_f;
    public:
    tmpClass(tmpStruct& myStruct);

    high_prec_t myFun();
};
#endif
```

example.cpp

```
#include "example.hpp"
#include <iostream>
tmpClass::tmpClass(tmpStruct& myStruct): m_x { myStruct.x }, m_y { myStruct.y }, m_z { myStruct.z }, m_w { myStruct.w }{ m_f = myStruct.f; };
high_prec_t tmpClass::myFun()
{
    return m_f*m_x;
};
```

example.i

```
%module example
%{
    #include "example.hpp"
%}
%include "example.hpp"
```

Comment: The first result in a Google search shows the duplicate: [Swig: How to wrap double& (double passed by reference)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470641/swig-how-to-wrap-double-double-passed-by-reference)

Comment: That question uses  a simple double type, while I am using my own struct

Comment: You used INPUT but it's wrong. You take arguments by (non-const) reference, I would expect OUTPUT (or INOUT) instead.

Comment: As for using a struct/class or a numeric type, it works the same with SWIG. [This other duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331791/passing-reference-from-python-to-c-function-wrapped-with-swig-for-return-value) does it with `std::string` which is a struct/class.

Comment: The casting doesn't work for some reason. You will have to compile the wrapper with `-g` and run it in the debugger. Set a breakpoint on `SWIG_Python_ConvertPtr` and check what is the problem. The problem is not obvious from what you have posted and it is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but what do you mean by run it in the debugger? Its supposed to be run from a python script, but I dont think that would work by setting breakpointss. I also added a MWE that reproduces the exact error I'm recieving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah, I figured out the issue thanks to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71786171/swig-c-to-python-how-to-wrap-a-function-that-passes-a-reference-to-a-struct). the issue was, in the python interpreter, I was not calling the struct as

```
example.tmpStruct()
```

but rather

```
example.tmpStruct
```

so the structure was not being initialized. Initializing the structure properly and passing it to the class constructor works as intended.